# Enviar formulario después de comprobar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como puedo hacer para que el formulario f2 se envie una vez que ya no hay errores.
Todo funciona bien marcando los errores, pero cuan do son subsanados no hace el submit.
Gracias y un saludo

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const f2 = $('#f2');

  f2.on('submit', event => {
    let errorCount = 0,
      requestPromiseArray = [];


    event.preventDefault();
    f2.find('.concepto').each(function(i, elem) {
      elem.className = 'concepto pending';
      let conceptos = elem.value,
        requestPromise = $.post("procesa-gastosprivado.php", {
          conceptos
        }).then(function(mensaje) {
          errorCount += (mensaje == 'error') ? 1 : 0;
          elem.classList.remove('pending');
          elem.classList.add(mensaje);

        });
      requestPromiseArray.push(requestPromise);

    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: Indica que es lo que te muestra en la consola para poder orientarnos un poco más

Answer (score 0):

Lo tienes casi hecho!

- El problema es que haces varias consultas AJAX para comprobar los datos, pero tienes que esperar que todas ellas se hayan completado para saber si hay errores.

La solución es usar Promise.all con el array de promesas que has estado guardando para asegurarte de que todas se han completado y entonces decidir si haces el submit:

```
 Promise.all(requestPromiseArray).then(values => {
   if (!errorCount) {
     f2.submit();
   }
 }
```